# Merge rows and join matching values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I have two sets of data on the first set there is one column that has a list of IDs like below.

[image]

I have another set which could have several rows matching that same ID like below

[image]

I am trying to get all the 'Values' shown in the second worksheet for each ID so I end up with something like

[image]

How do I write the equation in the B column to do the cross matching?

Comment: what have you tried? Also, shouldn't b2 contain: 23, 232, 1112 - or do you want them separated into 3-digit sequences?

Comment: I've tried VLOOKUP but that stops after the first match, I'm trying Macros now but it seems to be getting complicated quickly.

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889056/excel-multiple-vlookups-to-pull-in-1-data-element - or this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/how-to-look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-multiple-corresponding-values-HA001226038.aspx

Comment: Desired output doesn't match description of process. -1

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any Excel functions that return a range of cells. There are two possible other ways I can think of:

1. Write a VBA macro. You could build the first column using the `Remove Duplicates` feature. Then the code could loop over the range looking for matching values that match the ID and build a comma separate string.
2. Use a Pivot Table to do that:

   1. Select the ID, Year and Value range of cells and select `Pivot Table` on the `Insert` tab.
   2. Add the ID and Value fields to the Row Labels
   3. Configure Field Settings to No Subtotals and 'Show Items labels in tabular form'
   4. Get a layout something like this. You might be able to get it to layout in a single row but I couldn't find the option for that.

[image: pivt]